# APK not install when run the App after updation on Existing App

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-install-apk

I have already Published App in Play Store. Now I add few things and want to upload it with new color and options but when I click on Run in Android Studio the "error message shown" as attached in img url here. I update my previous VersionCode from '1' to '2' and VersionName from '2.0' to '3.0'. But still not install apk in my Debug Device to check before published.
Where I missing and what exactly this error msg tell. Please help to solve this error. No Coding error in Android Studio found.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v4T7.jpg

Comment: Maybe your Signature is wrong or different build variants!

Comment: I know my signature , now how to use to solve this with signed signature. @MehranZamani

Comment: use old one which is in app build.gradle file. I think you know that.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you want to launch app that already install on device .In some device android studio unable to uninstall and relaunch the app so first uninstall app from device then try to launch. Or in some device like xiaomi when you try to launch app from android studio, a prompt show on device to allow installation when you not allow then it show that error.

Answer (score 0):

just delete the existing app manually and run the debugger

Answer (score 0):

First, follow delete application and then after you can restart your device. You can add version code display for text to display version-name

String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;